# Scripting language to use with Redis

Tags: scripting, redis

I am working on application which needs to fetch values from database and pass the result in form of XML. Considering all the factors (basically, speed), I guess red is will be the vest choice.

Now I need to decide on the scripting language to use. I am well versed with PHP, but concerned about how it will behave at heavy load. Any other suggestion?

Comment: What type of load are you talking about? If you are on the extreme end a combination of lau / redis and nginx are what I would recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me Node.js worked very well with Redis. The module to use to connect to Redis is
node_redis

https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

if you need to parse XML you can use xml2js

https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js

Answer (score 1):

There is Lua and several others. See http://redis.io/clients.

Comment: I have to make request via web interface and make an output in form of xml. something like http://url/arguments. Which one of them is most suited for this purpose and has shorter learning curve.